# Refactoring WPF code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, db2

I have a method called get Data which executes my SQL and returns some rows of ContactLists containing Aggregated Labels.At the moment this method is in my code behind and would like to move it to a separate Data Access class. I would appreciate your assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is normal, if i understand your code, you do this operation after ContactList initialization:

```
contactList.Labels = new ObservableCollection<Label>()
{ 
   new Label() { 
      Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(), 
       Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"]) 
   } 
};
```

For each ContactList is always added one item, you will do something like this:

```
contactList.Labels = new ObservableCollection<Label>();
foreach(var item in <yourLabelDataSource>)
    contactList.Labels.Add(new Label(...));
```

The solution is like this:

```
    Dictionary<int, ContactList> myContactDictionary = new Dictionary<int, ContactList>();

    using (DB2DataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CONTACT_LIST_ID"]);
            if (!myContactDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
            {

                ContactList contactList = new ContactList();

                contactList.ContactListID = id;
                contactList.ContactListName = dr["CONTACT_LIST_NAME"].ToString();

                contactList.Labels = new ObservableCollection<Label>() 
                { 
                    new Label() 
                    { 
                        Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(), 
                        Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"]) 
                    } 
                };

                myContactDictionary.Add(id, contactList);
            }

            else 
            {
                //Add new label because CONTACT_LIST_ID Exists 
                ContactList contactList = myContactDictionary[id];
                contactList.Labels.Add(
                    new Label()
                        {
                            Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(), 
                            Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"])                                         
                        }
                    );
            }

        }
    }
```

Ben, for your last question you can use this solution:

```
            else 
            {
                //Add new label because CONTACT_LIST_ID Exists 
                ContactList contactList = myContactDictionary[id];
                string name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString();
                var label = contactList.Labels.Where(l => l.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
                if( label != null )
                    label.Count += Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"]);
                else
                {
                    contactList.Labels.Add(
                        new Label()
                        {
                            Name = dr["LABEL_NAME"].ToString(), 
                            Count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["LABEL_COUNT"])                                         
                        }
                    );
                }
```

I hope this code is readable and helpfulL!
                }

This is other response:

1. Create and Object Model that can contain your required data:

   ```
   public class DataResult
   {
       public ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel> AggregatedLabels { get; set; }
       public ObservableCollection<ContactList> ContactLists { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. You can build a method that return DataResult object, in your method (GetData()), you can valorize the two different properties (AggregatedLabels and ContactsList) with your DB Result. In the and you can return DataResult Object.

A little example here:

```
public DataResult GetData()
{
   DataResult result = new DataResult();
   result.AggregatedLabels = new ObservableCollection<AggregatedLabel>();
   result.ContactLists = new ObservableCollection<ContactList>();

   // Manipulate data result with your method logic like in this examle:
   foreach(var something in dbResult)
   {
       ContactList cl = new ContactList() { 
       //Binding from something
       }
       result.ContactLists.Add(cl);
   }
   return result; //return your Object Model with required Data!
}
```

I hope it is conceptually clear

Comment: Thanks Roby, i'm not sure what to put on the last line can you assist me

Comment: Ben we need to know something about data source, the structure of result in SqlDataReader, then i can help you!

Comment: So the code I have provided above adds the ContactList objects to the Dictionary. After that I will add all the objects to an ObservableCollection of ContactLists but at the moment it will only get the first Label for each ContactList.

Comment: i want know something about source, have duplicated records with const CONTACT_LIST_ID and different Labels?

Comment: The SQL returns me a row with contactListId, Name, LabelId and LabelName. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes I have duplicated records with the same contactListId

Comment: So one ContactList can have many Labels but a Label can only belong to one ContactList

Comment: Ok... i edit my answer, you can see the solution, is in the else case! :)

Comment: The solution is your idea! Just you don't notice it! (Excuse for my bad english, i'm italian). Good job Ben!

Comment: Roby, I have another question! How can I modify the "else" part of your solution so that before adding a new Label, it will check if that LABEL_NAME already exists in the Label collection and if this is true it will not add the LABEL_NAME again. Instead it will add the value of LABEL_COUNT to the existing Label. E.g if the value of LABEL_COUNT was 3 and the new value is 2 then the LABEL_COUNT will become 5. I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Roby, I have one last question for you! I have edited the question please take a look when you can. Thanks!

Comment: well.. let me know, you want export out of this MainWindow the method GetData, GetData retunr two Object, an AggregatedLabel's Array and ContactList's Array? True?

Comment: OK, I've done! :) see the post. (i'm not able to ask your question from now to the next three hours, i'm busy with company)

Comment: Thank you again! Sorry for the questions! :)

Comment: Have you understand? Code is helpfull?

Comment: I don't fully understand - does this mean that I can remove all the code from my code behind?

Comment: I was expecting to have no code in MainWindow.xaml.cs - something like MVVM?

Comment: Yes! Using this pattern you can be able to crate a ViewModel linked directly with Window DataContext Property. DataResult can be the DataContext of your window